# Reading multiple Excel files from the Directory - Python Code Not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to read all the excels file from the directory (esp. `Test_File.xlsx`). The code work when I just want to see the files on the terminal, but it gives an error (traceback) when I try to append all the `TEST_Files.xlsx` into one `Test4.xlsx`.

ERROR MESSAGE :

```
  File "Excel_Script3.py", line 16, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet1')
  File "/Users/ItsMyFuckingSystem/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/exce‌​l.py", line 163, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/ItsMyFuckingSystem/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/exce‌​l.py", line 206, in init
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "/Users/ItsMyFuckingSystem/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py‌​", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb") 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test_File_1.xlsx'
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Error is traceback. I'm able to read all the excels file within the same folder, but as soon as I want to read the excels from the whole directory, it screws up.

Comment: It's difficult to know if you fail to find a file, fail to open it or fail to append the data onto your dataframe without seeing the error.

Comment: I created a whole folder "Folder 1" and placed a Test_File.xlsx inside it, and than within Folder 1, I created Folder 2 ...3...4 with a same file name as Test_File.xlsx (but with different data). If I place all the Test_file.xlsx in the folder 1, I can see a test4.xlsx with all the data inside it. But when my files are scattered in different folders, my code doesn't works.

Comment: File "Excel_Script3.py", line 16, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet1')
  File "/Users/ItsMyFuckingSystem/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 163, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/ItsMyFuckingSystem/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "/Users/ItsMyFuckingSystem/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")

Comment: contd.  
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test_File_1.xlsx'

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information.

Comment: `os.path.join(root, filename)` ← this is the path that you should pass to `open(...)`

Comment: print the filename on the line above line 16 where your problem occurs

Comment: Resolved. thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will give the filename including the full path. In your code you are using filename twice (once with dirs, once with filenames). The filename does not contain any path information, but root does.
See:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.xlsx') and filename.startswith('Test_File'):
            print (os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to read the file twice in your inner loop:

```
...
data = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet1')
print(os.path.join(root, filename))
data = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet1')
...
```

The first one is redundant if all the files are in the root directory, but both will fail if they are in subdirectories. I would do the following:

```
...
full_filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
data = pd.read_excel(full_filename, 'Sheet1')
...
```